# how to bypass smtp server in sending emails in unix

Tags: email, script, smtp

I have a script to monitor server activities such as cpu usage and memory utilization which then saves it on to a text file. The script is running in unix-hux however, I dont know the SMTP server and the client isn't willing to allow me access. Is it possible send it through email without an SMTP server?

Comment: When you say SMTP server you're meaning the client's local one right?  Why not just use Google's?

Answer (score 2):

If you are able, try installing Postfix or another MTA on the server and use it as the SMTP server. In the script you could then use the mail command to send mail.